# Why I am getting this message "IAB TCF v2.0 errors detected, Error 3.3" to my AdMob account?

Tags: ios, admob, fundingchoices

I am getting this message in my AdMob account.

IAB TCF v2.0 errors detected We've detected an issue on your IAB TC string on one or more of your sites or apps. These errors may affect your ability to serve ads to European users. A detailed report is available for you on the EU user consent page.

[image]

And as I found error 3.3 indicates that The TC string last updated date was more than 13 months ago. and the suggested action is CMP should delete the old TC string and reobtain consent.
And I am using **Funding Choices** as a CMP, so how can I resolve this issue?
Do I need to do any changes to the app for it?

Please guide me on the solution if anyone has solution of this issue, it will be very helpful to me

Thanks

Comment: I get this error again in my AdMob account

Comment: I see this error too. Did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [that Google group](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/MUPYWR-ZlhQ) if you are using `UMP SDK`, and you probably are as you're using Funding Choices like me, it should be handled by the SDK itself. So nothing to worry about, if the error persist, meaning it present itself in several different days, than I fear the only way is to open a ticket with Google Admob.